# $cordovaFile.removeFile() doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ngCordova inside an Ionic mobile app. In one of my services, I need to delete files I've written previously with $cordovaFile

```
    remove: function (card) {
      //remove a card from the store
      var index = cardStore.indexOf(card);
      if (index > -1) {
        //remove the image files
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
          if (card.imgFrontUrl) {
            $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, "vid-front-" + card.id + ".jpg").then(function () {
              $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, "vid-front-" + card.id + ".jpg").then(function (result) {
                console.log("File '" + card.imgFrontUrl + "' deleted", JSON.stringify(result));
              }, function (err) {
                console.error("Failed to delete file '" + card.imgFrontUrl + "'", JSON.stringify(err));

              });
            }, function(err) {
              console.log("File '" + card.imgFrontUrl + "' does not exist", JSON.stringify(err));
            });
          }
```

Everything claims to be successful. In my logs, I see:

```
14    337901   log      File 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/vid-front-49444.jpg' deleted, {"success":true,"fileRemoved":{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"vid-front-49444.jpg","fullPath":"/vid-front-49444.jpg","filesystem":"<FileSystem: sdcard>","nativeURL":"file:///storage/emulated/0/vid-front-49444.jpg"}}
```

At this point I think it's a bug in $cordovaFile or other platform issue.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Are you testing on Anrdoid Marshmallow? If Yes, Which version of file plugin are you using?

Comment: Yes, Android 6.0.1 and cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0. I have also tested on Android 4.4.4 with the same behavior.

Comment: thought it could be permission issue related to marshmallow. Could you try out the approach used in following link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733512/delete-cachedirectory-cache-cordova-file-system-ionic hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Gandhi I'll give that a go. I found that the files may have been  deleted, but perhaps in a lazy fashion. Any attempt to load the file contents after a removeFile() would fail, but a file record still existed on the file system for a while after deletion. The file size would change each time I refreshed. This problem was made worse by trying to browse the files via MTP through Windows Explorer. Only a reboot of the phone would clear out the (now zero length) files.

Comment: Thats an interesting issue. But have tested the code which i sent you in both android and iOS device. It works fine

Comment: Agreed. All is well on the device itself. MTP might be slow to reflect the change, but I'm not worried about it as long as it works on the device.

Comment: How can I pass this function to sqlite function which delete the same file url from db , I mean how can both delete the same file url at the same time , from db and filesystem !

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it works on the device. But if you're viewing the files on the device through MTP (e.g. mounted through Windows Explorer), you may not see the change reflected immediately or at all until a device restart. Use a file browser app on the device as a sanity check instead if you're facing this issue.